# I m Not Able to Create any Function on gcp ? Firebase Deploy function error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Deploy Fails.

Coz "HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service ssrjivayuhomeopathyclinic. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 10"

Does it get Refreshed Monthly As mentioned in Quotas ??

Firebase deploy is Failing with error!

Project is nextjs hosted in firebase, ssr in gcp.

I Deleted the Function previously, and deployed , it worked that time

But I m Stuck With the Quotas.

CAn anyone tell me , When it get refreshed or i m done here!

```
    functions: HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service ssrjivayuhomeopathyclinic. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed
10.
    Consider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account.
    !  functions: failed to create function projects/jivayu-homeopathy-clinic/locations/asia-east1/functions/ssrjivayuhomeopathyclinic
    Failed to create function projects/jivayu-homeopathy-clinic/locations/asia-east1/functions/ssrjivayuhomeopathyclinic
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a quota issue to me, although I could be wrong - it sounds like a configuration issue. Please tell us more about how this is configured.

Comment: Thanks Fr Response jon. Can You Suggest issues related like this ? Every thing is good at times of npm run build, and before two days its all going well. Currently showing Quota issues. Function is not deploying yet. not from other Google Account i setup.

Comment: I am having this exact problem. Was just about to post a question actually. This just started and I have not touched the function's code for close to months. Starting to think this a Google issue on their end

Comment: Just for clarity, this is a gen2 function for me, runs with (specified) 512mb memory and runs in response to completion of a resize event from the firebase storage extensions. @JonSkeet any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Taio: We still know almost nothing about how either you or the OP have configured or deployed your functions. It *may* be an issue in GCF - I don't know. But without more details, it's going to be hard to reproduce.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem and this popped up two days ago. Until then I was able to update my functions with no issues. For reference my configuration as below:

```
gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> \
  --gen2 \
  --runtime python310 \
  --memory 512MB \
  --entry-point run_job \
  --source . \
  --region europe-west2 \
  --timeout 540s \
  --trigger-topic <TOPIC_NAME> \
  --env-vars-file .functions.dev.yaml
```

Answer (score 6):

I think I had exactly the same issue, I solved it by adding maxInstances to the function like this:

```
exports.helloworld = onRequest(
    {timeoutSeconds: 15, cors: true, maxInstances: 10},
    (req, res) => {
      res.send("I am a function.");
    },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a function with Python for 2nd gen Cloud Functions then you can use max_instances parameter in the decorator like this:

```py
@https_fn.on_call(max_instances=10)
def foo(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> any:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `--max-instances` flag explicitly. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first deployment of v2, then it's likely all you need to do is wait. In my case, it took approximately 30 minutes for Cloud Run to create a new service.

To double-check if this is your case, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/functions, open your function, and check if it shows the "Creating Cloud Run Service" status.

Logs even say: since this is your first time using functions v2, we need a little bit longer to finish setting everything up, please retry the deployment in a few minutes.

But I didn't expect "a few minutes" to last half of an hour. Someone on Reddit mentioned it that it can take anywhere between 0.5 to 1h from their experience